# how v8 encodes pointers in memory

Tags: google-chrome, pointers, v8

V8 version 10.7.0 (candidate)

I have created an array of elements from several objects

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxns0.png)

with v8 builtin functions, use "%DebugPrint" to get pointer to array object

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZrNH.png)

I look in memory for the address of the array object "0x000001BE0010BC5D",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyNk1.png)

and I see that the first address corresponds to the map of the object
the map address is encrypted

I would love to know how to decode the address manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not encrypted, it's [compressed](https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression). So it helps to print 32-bit values in your disassembler; in this case that'd be `0x002c3b51` for the array's map (lower half of the 64-bit value that you printed). Since all objects live on the same heap, you can manually decompress that address by adding the same upper-32-bits prefix that the array's address has, i.e. `0x000001be`. So the map's full address is `0x000001be002c3b51` (as you can already see in your second screenshot).

The upper half of that first 64-bit value is the compressed version of the array's second field, to its "properties" backing store.

Side note: please learn how to post code as code, not as screenshots.